# Can't pass the number of the objects from an NSMutableArray to a NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I thought it will be easy, but i can't solve this problem. I have an `NSMutableArray` called `resultNumbers` and i would like to display it's objects count in a `UILabel`. The problem is that i can not pass the number of the objects to the `numbers` string.

I'm getting this error in the line of the `NSString *numbers`:

```
Implicit conversion of 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int') to 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC
```

My code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.simRelation = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"searchHere"];
    NSString *numbers = [self.resultNumbers count];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    PFQuery *query = [self.simRelation query];
    [query orderByAscending:@"date"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
        else {
            self.resultNumbers = objects;

        }
    }];
    self.contactCounts.text = @"numbers";

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't magically turn things that are not NSStrings into NSStrings just by assigning them to a pointer to an NSString. You need to create an NSString with the value you want.

One way:

```
NSString *numbers = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)self.resultNumbers.count];
```

Another way:

```
NSString *numbers = [@(self.resultNumbers.count) stringValue];
```

Comment: With the first version i'm getting this error `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` and Xcode wants to change it to `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)self.resultNumbers.count];`The second way works but it displays 0 when i NSLog the `numbers` it.

Comment: @sabin: The error with the first line doesn't make sense, because what Xcode wants to change it to is exactly what I wrote. You might have copied it incorrectly. The 0 you're getting with the second one is probably correct — are you sure that `self.resultNumbers` has any objects at that point?

Comment: Yes, i'm using the same query for a table view in another class and it works well. But i will try to query directly for the number of the objects maybe it's possible.

Comment: @sabin: What I'm saying is that `viewDidLoad` is quite early in the view's lifecycle. In the code you've posted, that variable is never assigned to until `viewWillAppear:`, which is *after* `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: It seems that the second version is working fine. Thank you! I've tried it in the viewWillAppear as you said and the NSLog writes out the correct number. But there is one more thing that i don't understand. I would like to display this number in a label with this line `self.contactCounts.text = self.numbers;` , but nothing happens. I think this line is correct, but do you have idea what did i wrong?

Comment: @sabin: If you're actually doing `NSString *numbers = …`, then you can't access that as `self.numbers`. We've just declared a local variable here, not an object property.`self.numbers` accesses the `numbers` **property** of the current object. If you want to assign to that, use `self.numbers = …`.

Comment: Thanks @Chuck for coming back to help me. Fortunately i've discovered an other query called `countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:`. I think it will make everything easier, because it returns an int at the end of the query.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do it by an Stringwithformat

```
NSString *numbers = [NSString stringWithFormat @"%i", [self.resultNumbers count]];
```

it's complicated to xCode solve all cast of variables

enjoy  : )

Comment: I'm getting the `Expected ']'` error with this solution.

Comment: something missing before ?, this is the same line that i have in this moment on my code : )